# getCensus API for CPS March supplement

Tags: r

I'm trying to get county-level data from the Current Population Survey March supplement 1995-2005. I'm using the getCensus API to do this in **R**.

When I review the APIs I can see that the March supplement is available for my years of interest:

```r
apis = listCensusApis()
apis = apis[which(apis$vintage>=1995 & apis$vintage<=2005),]
cpsMar = apis[which(apis$name =="cps/asec/mar")]
view(cpsMar)
```

But when I try to call one year of this data:

```
CPS_1995 <- getCensus(
  name = "timeseries/cps/asec",
  vars = c("for", "in", "ucgid", "H_TENURE", "FEARNVAL"),
  region = "county",
  year = 1995
)
```

I get this error message:

> Error in apiParse(req) : The Census Bureau returned the following error message: HTTP Status 404 ? Not Foundbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}HTTP Status 404 ? Not Found Your api call was:  https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/cps/asec?

How do I reformat the code to successfully execute the call, and can this be done for all years of interest at once?

I've tried adding more variables to the variables call and changing `year` to `vintage`. Doesn't seem to help.